# Zoom map to display overlay in entire display area

Tags: iphone, scroll, overlay, zooming, mapkit

I have added overlay on map. I don't know how to make map zoom upto certain level so overlay will display over entire display area. Here I need what should be zoom level so my overlay will display in entire display area or any other way to do it. For clarification I don't want to restrict the user to scroll outside of this overlay area.
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
 [<mapView> setVisibleMapRect:[<overlayView> boundingMapRect]];
```

Thanks,

Comment: Not working for me. Because I want map should be zoom to that overlay area. And its not doing that way.

Comment: Still I am looking for reply or wise answer or tip